# Tabris.js playground examples do not work due to async function

Tags: javascript, tabris-js

I want to start coding with Tabris.js, and try to get some experience with the playground. But every example which uses 
async function asyncFunctionName(...) 
doesn't start. The error message is:

```
Could not load main module: Error: Could not parse ./app.js:./app.js:7:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token function
async function showActionSheet() {
      ^^^^^^^^
com.eclipsesource.v8.V8ScriptCompilationException
at subscribe (./cordova.js:758:11)
at addEventListener (./cordova.js:133:34)
at _entryPoint (./cordova.js:1560:18)
```

The simple examples like hello.js work well. The shipped examples in the tabris developer app work well.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the output of [what the Playground generates](https://pastebin.com/raw/GxBDYghL) to [what's inside the app](https://pastebin.com/raw/ycxd4hrW) they are definitely different.  Tabris.js on Android [does not yet support the async/await syntax](https://github.com/eclipsesource/J2V8/issues/334) natively (but iOS does).

This looks like a bug in implementation of the Playground, so it'd be worthwhile to [open an issue](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/issues) for that.  In the meantime, you can also clone the repo and run the snippets using [the instructions included in the `snippets` directory](https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js/tree/master/snippets#running-a-snippet):

```sh
npm install -g tabris-cli
git clone https://github.com/eclipsesource/tabris-js
cd tabris-js/snippets
tabris serve -m dist/actionsheet.jsx
```